# PHP/sql, join two tables and get an array

Tags: php, sql

I have two sql tables :

```
table_A : 
ID     VALUE
1      a
2      b
3      c
4      d

table_B : 
ID     VALUE
2      oA
4      oB
1      oC
3      oD
```

I'm looking for an sql query for get this php array :

```
$myarray = (
    "a" => "oC",
    "b" => "oA",
    "c" => "oD",
    "d" => "oB",
);
```

Is it possible to get this result with one query ? Can you help me ?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with an `INNER JOIN`. Here's a PDO example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.VALUE AS aVal, b.VALUE AS bVal FROM table_A a INNER JOIN table_B b ON a.id = b.id';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $result[$row['aVal']] = $row['bVal'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or...

```
Select '"' + a.Value + '" => "' + b.Value + '",'
From table_A a join table_B b
   on b.Id = a.Id
```